# Localization within Database - Right approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, localization

I have been doing a lot of reading on how to approach a database design if you wish to support multiple languages within your database.  However, before I did any research I first figured out how I would do it.  My approach was very simple, use 1 table with 3 columns:

```
Name (resource name)
Value (the value of the resource)
Culture (hold the culture and language, such as 'en-US'
```

The idea is to simply query from it by culture and Name.

Then After I did some research I found that there are 4 main approaches, listed in [this](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/data-modeling-for-multiple-languages-how-to-design-a-localization-ready-system) guide.

Now from my particular example, I am using mvc5 and using Resource files as well.  So all the labels, title pages, things that do not ever change are stored there.  However, messages such as "Thank you for registering" and notifications that should be changed through the CMS I want to use a database for.  The table is not going to grow very much and it would be on the client to setup messages for each of resources.  If the resource is not found I want to crash the page so that they know they missed a reference.

My question is, what is so wrong with my approach?  What are the things I am overlooking?

I have considered the scenario of the record for one language exist and not for another.  My result would be to crash the application with a detailed message as to what they are missing so that they could go and add it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach so long as it works for you. There are many different ways to accomplish this. And when you say "crash the page" I'm hoping that includes a helpful message indicating which resource is missing and not simply "unknown error."

Comment: @DanWilson well the end user would get the custom generic message, but the logs would indicate what is missing.

Comment: IMHO, crashing a page because a label is not there... seems to me a bit harsh to the user, I would use a default text and add a warning on the top of the screen reading `Some of the text may not display in the correct language`. But I don't see why a user may be punished for a missing translation. That is just a humble opinion :)